# Making the font size smaller in this mdframed, and turning into a reusable environment

Tags: environments, fontsize, mdframed, tabbing

I am very close to getting the `mdframed` setting that I want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,twoside=true,lmargin=4cm,
rmargin=4cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\noindent Surrounding text.

\begin{mdframed}
\begin{tabbing}
 some great \=code\\
            \>next line
\end{tabbing}
\end{mdframed}

\noindent Surrounding text.

\end{document}
```

Two questions:

1. How do I make the font size within the `mdframed` environment `\small`?
2. How can I turn this into a reusable environment, such that I won't have to begin and end both the `mdframed` and `tabbing` environments every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach without additional packages is to define a new environment; in the following example, the environment `myenv` does what you want and hasan optional argument to pass options to `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1][]
  {\begin{mdframed}[font=\small,#1]\begin{tabbing}}
  {\end{tabbing}\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\noindent Surrounding text.

\begin{myenv}
 some great \=code\\
            \>next line
\end{myenv}

\noindent Surrounding text.

\begin{myenv}[backgroundcolor=red!20]
 some great \=code\\
            \>next line
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Use `\mdfsetup{font=\small}` to add `\small` to every `mdframed` environment. To enclose a `tabbing` environment within `mdframed`, you may use the [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package and its `\xapptocmd` and `\xpretocmd` macros.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\mdfsetup{font=\small}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\mdframed}{\begin{tabbing}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\endmdframed}{\end{tabbing}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\noindent Surrounding text.

\begin{mdframed}
 some great \=code\\
            \>next line
\end{mdframed}

\noindent Surrounding text.

\end{document}
```

An alternative that does without `xpatch` is to issue `\surroundwithmdframed{tabbing}` in the preamble and to use `tabbing` environments in the document body. Note that -- contrary to the above solution -- this won't allow to add optional arguments to individual environments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\surroundwithmdframed[font=\small]{tabbing}

\begin{document}

\noindent Surrounding text.

\begin{tabbing}
 some great \=code\\
            \>next line
\end{tabbing}

\noindent Surrounding text.

\end{document}
```

Output for both examples:

[image]